# How are the sound effects of the Shaw brothers martial art movies produced?

Tags: martial-arts, sound-effects

Beforehand I admit I like those old martial art movies from the Shaw Brothers. Recently looking "Five Element Ninjas" after a long time I noticed that the sound effects are very distinct from the now dominant movies. It is in fact so distinct that I am confident to identify a SB fight at once.

Omnipresent is the typical sharp "fuuddd" when striking and a very high-pitched dang for weapon hits.

Has anyone information about the foley artists of Shaw Brothers and how they produced the typical martial art sounds, especially the "fuuddd" sound ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using a variety of objects including boxing gloves, leather gloves, a heavy sheet, and what appears to be wood

In the documentary *Fists of fire*, which explores the Shaw Brothers studio, we see how they use the different materials to generate the effects for a fight scene.

Comment: Would have given you 10 points. Excellent!